# is there a way to find an element using a data in a string in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am making a webscraper and have got a scraped number inside Pricefinal, for this instance right now it is 260, I am trying to find the xpath using the number I have inside Pricefinal but I am having issues with this line of code:

```
item = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Pricefinal')]")
```

When I execute the code it will only searh for the word Pricefinal instead of the value inside the string, I have tried using this code

````
item = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), "(pricefinal)")]")``` but am getting unmatched errors on ]
````

The url is [this](https://www.trademe.co.nz/Browse/SearchResults.aspx?&cid=9908&searchType=&searchString=ps4&x=0&y=0&type=Search&sort_order=&redirectFromAll=False&rptpath=202-&rsqid=28ea3fd324b9429c8e26e4ff6afdd91b-006&user_region=100&user_district=0&generalSearch_keypresses=0&generalSearch_suggested=0&generalSearch_suggestedCategory=&category_suggest=0).

Comment: show url and minimal working code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `XPATH axes` to find all descendants inside tag with text "pricefinal". 
If you have any difficulties just place here html part and i can give u better advice